# how to populate sysdate in apex_item.date_popup

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

i have created `apex_item.datepopup()` function to provide entry for user to select date from calendar,  it should populate sysdate bydefault..

```
APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP (2,ROWNUM,ISSUED_DATE,'dd-mon-yyyy')
```

Comment: Can't you set it as a **default value**?

Comment: Pls help ..its needed urgent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP (p_idx =>2 , p_value => SYSDATE , p_item_id =>  ISSUED_DATE, p_date_format =>  'DD-MON-YYYY') IssuedDate,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP (2,ROWNUM, nvl(ISSUED_DATE, sysdate),'dd-mon-yyyy')
```

Comment: Sorry Ivan ,Not Working

Answer (score 0):

Directly copied from my code where I have it

```
APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP (p_idx =>  2 , p_value => (CASE WHEN UPPER(cur_parameter.default) = 'SYSDATE' THEN SYSDATE WHEN UPPER(cur_parameter.default) != 'SYSDATE' AND cur_parameter.default IS NOT NULL THEN TO_DATE(cur_parameter.default) ELSE NULL END) , p_item_id =>  cur_parameter.name, p_date_format =>  cur_parameter.format , p_item_label =>  cur_parameter.name)
```

The CASE is because I keep the defaults stored in a table, and most of the time, the default date is sysdate, however, its viewed as a string and not SYSDATE. The cur_parameter is a row in a cursor.

If a call has more than one or two parameters, its always best to use named notation, avoids confusion and helps prevent mix ups.

Comment: Thank you very much TineO..it worked and I posted my code for the reference